# How to find in linux and delete directories that not match a name? !#Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to delete unpacked directories from my /source tree keeping the others with .tar and .patch extensions,

how to do please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BACKUP YOUR DIRECTORY FIRST, I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS, AND IT HAS A BUG AS NOTED IN THE COMMENTS.**

**WHILE IN THE ACTUAL /source DIRECTORY:**

```
ls|fgrep -v -e .tar -e .patch|xargs rm -rf
```

You probably want to use the "put echo after xargs" trick to see what this would actually do, before running it:

```
ls|fgrep -v -e .tar -e .patch|xargs echo rm -rf
```

Comment: This will actually break if there're any filenames with spaces. `-1` for showing bad practices to the entire world and future generations.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf feel free to edit my answers to correct bugs

Comment: @RobinGreen Not really, I can't fix anything that relies on parsing the output of `ls`. A totally different approach must be chosen: either using `find` as bjhaid did, or using globs.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
find . -not -name "*.tar" -not -name "*.patch" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

This is using only one command not using `pipes`.

**Note.** This will proceed recursively into subdirectories. If this is unwanted, use the `maxdepth` switch:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "*.tar" -not -name "*.patch" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```